# Very slow voltage step-up using boost converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm trying to build a 5-12V DC boost convertor but when powering it on the voltage rises very slowly and seems to stop climbing around 6.5V. The oscillator input is running at a frequency of 23255.82Hz with a duty cycle of 60%. I'm using an IRF540N Mosfet transistor as the switch, a 1N5822 Schottky diode, an LF-1102 100 micro Henery Inductor, a 100 micro Farad 50V electrolytic capacitor, and a NE556 timer as the oscillating source. The load is 20 ohms and is a solenoid valve (which I mention as I realize the coil in the load may be the issue?). While I have tried varying capacitance and adding a pull-down resistor on the MOSFET gate neither of these has had much of an effect. Any advice as to what the issue could be would be greatly appreciated!
[image]
Ignore the test points those were there while I tried to simulate the circuit

Comment: Why does your schematic show a 9 volt source?

Comment: You should use a low-level digital MOSFET like IRL540.

Comment: The inductor needs to have a high saturation current. Do you have a datasheet for the inductor.

Comment: The schematic you show uses wrong parts, e.g. not an IRF540 mosfet but a CMOS device used as an IC building block. This stack exchange has a built-in circuit simulator that you should use to draw the schematic and simulate it. It's adequate for your purpose.

Comment: Have resolved the circuit issues. Unfortunately I don't know the saturation current of the coil as it was made by my local store so will look into a different coil and get a IRL540N mosfet

Answer (score 1):

> Very slow voltage step-up using boost converter?

Here is the behavior with an IRL540 ... Too slow?
Amplitude PWM is 5 V.

[image]